# macOS - Java Runtime Environment 1.8 or 10 is required and should be installed before installing Teradata Studio Application

Tags: java, macos, teradata, macos-catalina

Good day,

I'm trying to install "Teradata Studio" on my Mac. This is a software for working with Teradata database.
However, at the end of installation I get an error **"Java Runtime Environment 1.8 or 10 is required and should be installed before installing Teradata Studio Application."**

Can anyone please tell me what can I do about it? I already installed Java 1.8.

output of terminal commands

**"/usr/libexec/java_home -V"**

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    14, x86_64: "Java SE 14"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
    13.0.2, x86_64: "Java SE 13.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_201, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
```

**java -version**

```
java version "1.8.0_201"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)
```

**echo $JAVA_HOME**

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
```

.bash_profile content:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home
```

So, looks like I already have Java 1.8. 
Any ideas why it's not working?

Comment: Changing JAVA_HOME in your user profile doesn't change the "system default" of *highest available* which is what will be used when you click on a .pkg file. You might be able to set JAVA_HOME and then manually install from a terminal window command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but noup. Doesn't work.
I used "sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package.pkg -target /" command and got the same error.

Comment: Possible clumsy workaround: Temporarily rename the *Contents/Info.plist* file for each of the other versions to something else, e.g. *Info.plist.disabled*. Install Studio, then rename the files back.

Comment: can you please share output of "which -a java"  command from your mac terminal

Comment: the output is: "/usr/bin/java"

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Get Java**

You can download and install many different versions of Java, including Java 11 for mac from here:

https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?package=jdk

**Step 2: Check your version**

Use the command `java --version` to identify which version of Java is currently active.

**Step 3: Remove other versions of Java**

If the version you just installed isn't showing, you may have multiple versions of Java installed on your machine.  In this case you may need to remove existing versions of Java that are not the version you want.  For Mac, java is typically installed in this directory:

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

To delete a version of Java from your machine, use the command "sudo rm -r *directory*" where *directory* is the name of the directory you want to remove.

**Step 4: Repeat until done**

Repeat steps 2 and 3 until your desired version of Java shows up during step 2.  then try installing your software.

Comment: This worked for me. It was defaulting to my v16 install. After removing, it defaulted to 11 which is accepted by teradatas install manager